# Data scraping using python webdriver

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver

[codesample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ayka.png)

I am trying to click a button using Firefox - python - webdriver

But every time error comes:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .pull-right show-toggle with-icon
```

Am I missing something here? after login and couple of steps I am reaching on one page where I need to click on the button with below class name.

```
child = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pull-right show-toggle with-icon')
child.click()
```

Any other way of doing this ?

Comment: Hmm... Actually with your code you should get `InvalidSelectorException` as search `by_class_name` doesn't support compound class names... Update your code with original selector. Also check whether your button located inside an `iframe`

Comment: Hi Andersson - the button is not under iframe, you can check HTML Page i have added

Comment: update your code with original selector, what actually this means?

Comment: It means that `driver.find_element_by_class_name('pull-right show-toggle with-icon')` should trigger `InvalidSelectorException`, but not `NoSuchElementException`... Also there is only little `HTML` sample on provided image. Are you sure that there is no `iframe`?

Comment: Infact i tried parent child relationship as well he is able to find class "Hidden Print" but then also for child it says no class name like this,

Comment: another thing which i have noted just now, when he is searching for the class name, if you see the error in question part, he is adding a dot (.) before the string...too many observation s:)

Comment: You should be careful with using class names, as class name of the same element could be different (dynamically changeable) depending on some events, like hovering over element, sending text to some input fields, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per provided piece of `HTML`, you can click your button with following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

button = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@data-toggle-text='Hide details']")))
button.click()
```

Comment: amazing thanks alot it worked finally, but will you be able to give me heads up what xpath is doing here

Comment: i got it, its interesting

Comment: `XPath` is more flexible than other approaches to locate element. In this particular `XPath` you check `DOM` for ancor with specific attribute (`data-toggle-text` in this case)

Comment: this is working fine for me but problem now is this button will sometimes exist or sometimes not, so when i am running my cude it throws timeout exception because the button is not present how can i build this condition that if you didn't find that button then exit the code

Comment: You can use `try`/`except` block: `try: button = wait(driver, 10)...  except TimeoutException: driver.quit()`

Comment: in place of driver.quit() can m i allowed to go to some label

Comment: i used pass in place of driver.quit() :)